# iOS 7 status bar overlapping with admob interstitial ads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, admob

I'm using phonegap

I'm trying to ad admob interstitial ads but the status bar is always overlapping

things i'v tried so far :

1) hide the status bar from info.plist, which does not work at all
2) hide the status bar with this line of code

```
    -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }
```

it does hide the status bar when the app is running but when the interstitial is displayed the status bar appears again,

how can i completely hide the status bar when interstitial is displayed ?

any help is much appriciated

Comment: The status bar in ios7 is a pita.  I recommend just hiding it all the time or assuming that it will always be there in which case you could lower your ad.  Or move the ad to the bottom.  Waiting to see how someone answers this.

Comment: yeah well my questions actually is I'm trying to find a way to hide it all the time, but thanks.

Comment: In the `Info` tab of your target do you have `Status bar is initially hidden` set to `Yes`

Comment: yes i managed to make it work, thank you